# How to remove default favicon completely?

Tags: magento-1.8

[image]

Magento favicon showing in product images
How do I delete this favicon permanently?

I have changed it in Magento panel it's changed in homepage but I open image link in new tab it shows Magento favicon again.

Answer (score 2):

- Clear your browser's cache.
- make sure favicon.ico has physically been deleted from the root, if it was there in the first place.  Some browsers will search for it there even if it is not mentioned in your HTML.

Source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/221384/

Answer (score 1):

**Try the following instruction in image. (attached)**

[image]

**And also**

[image]

Comment: The above instruction will helps to replace with your own favicon. If you wish to remove then delete from root (refer first image, delete skin/frontend/base/default/favicon.ico

Comment: in the main admin panel i have changed the favicon.but when i open image in new tab ,it's favicon is magento. help me in finding that icon

Comment: Remove favicon  from root folder (refer 1st image). Try clear cache